# Video format to get my comp to export under 50Kb

Tags: after-effects, file-formats, codec

I have an approx. 8s long video in Adobe After Effects CC, res. 200x200px. I need to export it so it has <= 50Kb, which format should I choose so it keeps the most quality but falls under these constraints?

-> [here is the .pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ygow4osue7ttogk/pravidla-tvorba-banneru.pdf?dl=0), but it's in Czech. The relevant info is translated lower:
->

format   size (px)  kB   length (s)

Square   200x200    50   unconstrained

Comment: What is the frame rate and needed color bit depth?  50KB (assuming you mean kilobytes, not kilobits) is VERY small for any length of video.  Even 200 by 200 video that is 256 color.

Comment: Right now I have 23.98FPS, but I guess there are no constraints as for the frame rate. I just want to know the best way to produce a very small file size. I tried H.264 with quality of 50 and it produced ~500Kb, but I need to cut it down even further..

Comment: What is the use case and why does it have to be so small?

Comment: I made a videobanner for a client, it's going to be shown on a website in 200x200px resolution. The client sent me a .pdf that shows the constraints for videobanners on that website, and the filesize says 50Kb. Is it possible they mean a flash video? Would that make a difference?

Comment: Can you possibly cut and paste the relevant portion of the PDF in to the question.  This is next to impossible.  Something has to be wrong with how you are reading it.

Comment: updated, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing the PDF, I can confirm that you are misreading it.  They are looking for a flash animation, not a video.  You will not be able to use your After Effects assets at all.  You need to remake the ad as a flash animation in Adobe Flash using vector graphics in order to fit within their 50KB limitation.

Comment: Hello, so I redone the animation in Adobe Flash. What do you recommend on export settings so I get it within the limitation?

Comment: How close are you? Did you use vector animation and assets?

Comment: Anything except pictures is vector. I'm currently at 9,8Mb.. probably caused by the large occurence of images.

Comment: You need to down size you images a lot. 9.8mb is gigantic for a flash animation.

Answer (score 0):

At 200px by 200px, you are looking at extreme levels of limitation.  You may want to consider something like a gif at that point unless you also need audio.  Just audio alone for 8 seconds completely blows your 50KB bandwidth budget.  50KB is a mind numbingly small amount of data.

At 8kbps, no raster video format will be usable, even at 10fps and 200 by 200 pixels with 256 color.  You might be able to use a swf animation to fit within that limitation, but even it would have to be stupidly highly optimized to fit within your limitation.

Are you sure you are reading the PDF correctly?  What you are talking about is virtually impossible.

Comment: I don't need audio. But in the .pdf I received, they're talking about a flash video. Is the needed filesize possible in Flash?

Comment: Which flash format is it talking about? FLV or SWF?

Comment: Either one I guess